# Attempting to convert a csv file into a list inside a function using list comprehension

Tags: python, csv

I would like to create a function (utilizing list comprehension) called `csv_printer()` that takes in the path of the csv file, a list of the columns that I want to print, and the option to change the delimiter that will be printed between each column.

The code I am starting off with:      `csv_printer(path='dssss.csv', columns=['Ext', 'Time Zone', 'Caller ID First Name'], delimiter='$')` that would print something like the following:

```
1001 $ Asia/Pacific $ VAN
1002 $ Asia/Atlantic $ ALT
```

My initial thought process is to convert the above code into a list inside of a function to hold it together.

```
import csv
with open("dssss") as csvfile:
     reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
     def csv_printer(path='dssss.csv', columns=['Ext', 'Time Zone', 'Caller ID First Name'], delimiter='$'):
         for row in reader:
             print dict(row)
```

No data is printed from the above code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do some research on how to use `def`.

With that aside you could try something like

```
import csv

def csv_printer(path='dssss.csv', columns=['Ext', 'Time Zone', 'Caller ID First Name'], delimiter='$'):
    with open(path, 'r') as csvfile:
        content = csv.reader(csvfile)

        #find columns, assumes they exist and are in the first row
        header = [x.strip() for x in next(content)]
        cols = [header.index(x) for x in columns]

        for row in content:
            print(delimiter.join([row[x] for x in cols]))

        return None #you can capture the output and return here if you want


csv_printer()
```

You will probably need to add some checks, like what happens if the columns you asked for don't exist.

Comment: That's working good except it's pulling an error at the the end. It prints the data I need but this appears at the end: 

    ```print (delimiter.join([row[x]for x in cols]))
    IndexError: list index out of range```

Also, is there a way to get the delimiter to have space before and after. Something in the join function rather than putting delimiter=' $ '

Comment: check that your columns match the actual columns in your test file... including whitespace

Comment: if you really want a space before and after every delimited you could add a line like delimiter = " "+delimiter+" "  although that is pretty ugly

Comment: Thanks, the delimiter line worked. One thing I noticed, when I change the columns to two instead of three, ex. `columns=['Status', 'Device']` instead of `columns=['Ext', 'Time Zone', 'Caller ID First Name']`, no error is printed.

Comment: Actually, I changed it to a few others and it worked fine. Maybe the combo of the three( 'Ext', 'Time Zone', 'Caller ID First Name') is problematic. I doublechecked with the csv file and it there are no mistakes.

Comment: I suspect that your column names have some leading or trailing whitespace in them, i.e. 'Time Zone' is actually ' Time Zone' . Hard to know without seeing it, but it can be fixed quickly with .strip(), see my added comment above

Comment: Thanks for the added comment. Just added it in and the error is still appearing. Hmmm, it's a strange one.

Comment: Oops! I made a mistake, put the .strip() in the wrong place - see new edit

Comment: Thanks for the update. Still getting the error. Strange, might be a corrupt csv, not sure.